# How does Google check username availability in few millisecond during Gmail signup?

Tags: caching, architecture, gmail, logic

I'm wondering, how does Google check username availability within few millisecond from list of 1 billion users? I want to know architecture and technology used to build username availability check service.

**My thoughts**
They will not be querying their database directly. They may be using cache memory but even after that it is very tough to scan 1 billion record in few millisecond without a perfect architecture.

Comment: Try this link to get a better understanding, "https://www.hackerearth.com/blog/developers/how-websites-check-username-availability-quickly/

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to that. It pretty much depends on architecture, technologies, bandwidth, processing power, everything. Surely there is a service specifically designed for that, which stores everything in memory, as the fastest way to work with data.